# Best way to parse JSON data into a .NET object

Tags: asp.net, json

What's the best way to parse JSON data into a .NET object?  I am trying to assist a coder friend of mine and he is trying to dump some data from a JSON string into a database using ASP.net.  Are there any prebuilt scripts that would make this happen?

Thanks in advance to any help.

Answer (score 22):

The .NET Framework 3.5 has the [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) class that can ease the deserialization. You can also use third party libraries like [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx).

Answer (score 14):

Actually you should really look at the [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx) as the JavaScriptSerializer was listed as **Obsolete** in the .NET 3.5 framework.

Admittedly ScottGu stated that it may have been a mistake and it may be reinstated in the future.

Comment: FYI, JavaScriptSerializer was undepricated in .NET 3.5 SP1.

http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2008/05/28/javascriptserializer-undeprecated-in-net-35-sp1/

Answer (score 2):

If you are using .NET 3.5, you probably don't need a third party library.  The JavaScriptSerializer class can be used (just repeating what was mentioned before) but you also have access to the DataContractJsonSerializer, which offers a different model for mapping between CLR objects and JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Arguably the fastest way is to use [JSON#](http://insidethecpu.com/2014/10/22/ultrafast-json-parsing/), which avoids reflection and the associated performance overhead - this can be significant in web applications. It also gives you much more control in terms of the parsing process itself.