# How does ASP.NET MVC Generate JsonResults?

Tags: .net, asp.net, javascript, asp.net-mvc, json

I want to inject some Json into the Html page returned by the server?

Is there a public function that returns the Json string when Json(someObject) gets called?

Note that I don't want to return Json to the browser in a seperate request. I want to convert an object graph to json and inject it into a script block.

Thanks

---

Looking at the MVC source code, I found this:

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
...
            // The JavaScriptSerializer type was marked as obsolete prior to .NET Framework 3.5 SP1
#pragma warning disable 0618
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            response.Write(serializer.Serialize(Data));
#pragma warning restore 0618
```

Why was it marked obsolete?

Comment: More info regarding how - `JavaScriptSerializer Serialize()` and rejects GET requests by default http://stackoverflow.com/a/3991940/516748

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help.

[Best way to parse JSON data into a .NET object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423294/best-way-to-parse-json-data-into-a-asp-net-object)

[Why microsoft made JavaScriptSerializer obsolete prior to .net 3.5 SP1 and again active after that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/536359/why-microsoft-made-javascriptserializer-obsolete-prior-to-net-3-5-sp1-and-again)

I usually use [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx) though.

Answer (score 0):

/*I think */it uses an instance of the System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer class.

Verified with reflector that it actually does. It's a default one too, no arguments to the constructor and no properties set before it's used.