# ASP.Net MVC: how to create a JsonResult based on raw Json Data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, serialization, jsonresult

Having a `string` containing the following raw Json data (simplified for the sake of the question):

```
  var MyString =  "{ 'val': 'apple' }";
```

How can I create a `JsonResult` object representing `MyString`?

I tried to use the Json(object) method. but it handles the raw json data as an string -logically :P-. So the returned HTTP response looks like:

```
"{ 'val': 'apple' }"
```

instead of the given raw Json Data:

```
{ 'val': 'apple' }
```

*this is what I want to achieve*:

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `Json()` method on `Controller` is actually a helper method that creates a new `JsonResult`. If we look at [the source code for this class](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/760c8f38678118734399c58c2dac981ea6e47046/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json/JsonResult.cs)<sup>*</sup>, we can see that it's not really doing that much -- just setting the content type to `application/json`, serializing your data object using a `JavaScriptSerializer`, and writing it the resulting string.. You can duplicate this behavior (minus the serialization, since you've already done that) by returning a `ContentResult` from your controller instead.

```
public ActionResult JsonData(int id) {
    var jsonStringFromSomewhere = "{ 'val': 'apple' }";
    // Content() creates a ContentResult just as Json() creates a JsonResult
    return Content(jsonStringFromSomewhere, "application/json");
}
```

---

<sup>*</sup> Starting in MVC2, `JsonResult` also throws an exception if the user is making an HTTP GET request (as opposed to say a POST). Allowing users to retrieve JSON using an HTTP GET has [security implications](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/25/json-hijacking.aspx) which you should be aware of before you permit this in your own app.

Comment: +1 - but according to http://json.org though, the keys and values need to be enclosed in double quotes and not single.

Comment: Nice catch. I just copied the string the asker used. Of course, this whole answer assumes that you *know* your JSON string is valid to begin with so the client's web browser doesn't choke on it.

Answer (score 1):

The way I have generated json data from a string is by using `JavaScriptResult` in the controller:

```
public JavaScriptResult jsonList( string jsonString)
{
   jsonString = "var jsonobject = new Array(" + jsonString + ");";
   return JavaScript(jsonString)
}
```

Then when you request pass the json string to that action in your controller, the result will be a file with javascript headers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the JavaScriptSerializer class for this

```
var js = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
var jsonObject = js.Deserialize("{ 'val': 'apple' }", typeof(object));
```

Comment: Would it work to serialize it as an object?  I don't think the serializer adds properties to the serialized object, I think it just looks for properties on the object that match the properties in the JSON.  Maybe you could try `dynamic` though?

Comment: This would deserialise the object only to have is serialised again.