# Pass string with Quote in Json result

Tags: c#, json, string, rest

I wanna send JSON response to browser that requested based on **REST** service. I use something like this **that includes some quotes** in Controller Method:

```
return Json("blah\"blah", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

And I expect the result would be `blah"blah` **But is** `blah\"blah` and **includes back slash too**! I wanna have `blah"blah` in response without any conversion in client side. I know that need to perform this via C# codes but how to do that?

Comment: `blah"blah` is illegal JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C# and JSON encode characters similarly. The string `blah"blah` is encoded in both C# and JSON as `"blah\"blah"`. It's perfectly expected, then, that your raw JSON includes the backslash.

When you decode that string with a proper JSON library, it again becomes the string `blah"blah`.

Comment: can I send decoded version in json format to browser?

Comment: @Amir you seem to be wanting a conflicting thing: the decoded version is `blah"blah`. If you send it as JSON, it's `"blah\"blah"`. Most likely, what you want to do is send it as JSON (which your code appears to be doing already) and then decode it on the client side, e.g. with `jQuery.parseJSON(myStr)` (if that's not automatically done).

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in two above threads:

1. [ASP.Net MVC: how to create a JsonResult based on raw Json Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3991751/asp-net-mvc-how-to-create-a-jsonresult-based-on-raw-json-data)
2. [How to output Json string as JsonResult in MVC4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18409863/how-to-output-json-string-as-jsonresult-in-mvc4)

So that I need to use something like this:

```
return Content(jsonStringFromSomewhere, "application/json");
```

With this in mind considering that JSONP is used in case of ajax requesting to external service or URL. But I wanna build specific string due to parse with a special parser and I used JSON rather than JSONP and result was great.