# How to: Send JSON structure to server and return file in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, json, design-patterns, client-server

I'm having a very hard time wrapping my head around this problem (it might be the heat from the summer finally arriving).

**Problem**:
I want the user to press a button *client side* which performs *javascript* data preparing and at last send a JSON structure to (currently a *asmx* webservice on) the server. The JSON structure is several levels deep.

*Server side* I create a PDF file which I want to send back to the user.

**Goal**:
The user feeling is that she presses a button and expects a PDF to return to her - either in a new window or as a download (preferrable).

**Tools**:
The system consists of (*client side*) HTML, JavaScript and ExtJS and (*server side*) *ASP.NET*.

Normally I would use an *ashx* handler to return a file to the client, but can I send a JSON structure to the handler and still be able to parse it correctly *server side*?

**I am searching for the pattern to use.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the client side: submit the JSON string as part of the form data.

On the server side: parse the JSON string (the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423294/best-way-to-parse-json-data-into-a-asp-net-object) list a number of JSON parsers usable in asp.net) and then generate the PDF. The header

```
Content-disposition: attachment; filename=something.pdf;
```

will make the PDF appear as a download for the user.

Comment: Currently I am using AJAX to send the request, is it possible to serve a file from the response from an AJAX request? I can see that my question is a bit to general here :)

Comment: @Chau: I don't think so. I think what you'd normally do here is have an invisible `<iframe>`, and build a form in it using javascript, then submit that form. This doesn't end up being much more complicated than using AJAX really... (Using an `<iframe>` avoids either having to change the URL of the current page, or opening an annoying popup window and/or creating a blank tab, in order to give the user the file download...).