# How to read JSON response in c#

Tags: c#, .net, json

I am using thirparty service to give me coordinates, below is the response I want to read this using c# .net in some kind of object so that I can use the information but confused how to achieve this..

```
{"found": 1, "bounds": [[52.45401, -1.96211], [52.45401, -1.96211]], "features": [{"id": 65140,"centroid": {"type":"POINT","coordinates":[52.45401, -1.96211]},"bounds": [[52.45401, -1.96211], [52.45401, -1.96211]],"properties": {"name": "B17 0SL"},"type": "Feature"}], "type": "FeatureCollection", "crs": {"type": "EPSG", "properties": {"code": 4326, "coordinate_order": [0, 1]}}}
```

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to parse JSON data into a ASP.net object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423294/best-way-to-parse-json-data-into-a-asp-net-object)

Comment: @BalaR this is not a nice answer......:) you could have helped more :)

Comment: This will help you!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474377/json-library-for-c-sharp

Comment: @RoyiNamir It's hard to put in any effort when you know the OP didn't even try to google to see what his options are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have a look at  Newtonsoft.Json its a package that will deserialize the Json into a class for you.

but you will need to create the class structure you want to use.

Comment: how can i create a class structure, I mean I dont know how this organized i am totally new to this.

Comment: @Shax i have found this project on Codeplex  http://jsonclassgenerator.codeplex.com/ its an app that will take the string and give you the class structure you can deserialise it to

Answer (score 2):

Use a json parser like [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx) or [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx)

For your case for ex., using [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/) & [dynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx) keyword, you can write

```
dynamic jObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonstr);
Console.WriteLine(jObj.found);
Console.WriteLine(jObj.features[0].bounds[0][0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JsonTextReader`. The following code segment may be useful, if you are not using JSON.NET

```
jsonString = {"found": 1, "bounds": [[52.45401, -1.96211], [52.45401, -1.96211]], "features": [{"id": 65140,"centroid": {"type":"POINT","coordinates":[52.45401, -1.96211]},"bounds": [[52.45401, -1.96211], [52.45401, -1.96211]],"properties": {"name": "B17 0SL"},"type": "Feature"}], "type": "FeatureCollection", "crs": {"type": "EPSG", "properties": {"code": 4326, "coordinate_order": [0, 1]}}};
JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(jsonString));

while (reader.Read())
{
   if (reader.Value != null)
   {
      // Read Json values here
      // reader.Path               -> Gives you the key part.
      // reader.Value.ToString()   -> Gives you the value part
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read the JSON like this:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("URL");

            JArray array = new JArray();
            using (var twitpicResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {

                using (var reader = new StreamReader(twitpicResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                    var objText = reader.ReadToEnd();

                    JObject joResponse = JObject.Parse(objText);
                    JObject result = (JObject)joResponse["result"];
                    array = (JArray)result["Detail"];
                    string statu = array[0]["dlrStat"].ToString();
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/)