# Regular expression for Replace jSon string

Tags: c#, regex, json

Hey I need a regular expression to replace the matching string with empty.

I have below json

```
{"session":{"convener_id":null,"convergence":false,"created_at":"2012-06-02T10:00:00","event_id":null,"id":42,"name":"Test Session","next_steps":"","notes":"","room":null,"status":0,"summary":"","time":"10:0","updated_at":"2013-06-03T11:49:45.3397898+05:30","people":null,"comments":null,"convener":null}}
```

I need a json to replace the null properties to empty so that I don't have any null properties. If any proeprties is null just remove that property. I know regular expression can do the tricks but I am not well versed in regular expression.

Comment: You are looking for some pain... Properly parsing nested braces (and correctly handing strings with them i.e. `"field:"b{a{a:null"`) is not easy with regular expressions. Please check answer by Sam on balancing braces in [all time favorite on regular expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454)

Comment: Can you do that with Javascript? Then all you need to do is `delete obj.property` where it is null. Otherwise you will probably need to parse json, there is a project called JSON.NET that can help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you to don't look at Regex for this case, instead use [JSONParser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423294/best-way-to-parse-json-data-into-a-net-object) for .Net. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507889/how-to-ignore-a-property-in-class-if-it-is-null-using-json-net) thread can help you on this issue.

Setting **JSONSerializer.NullValueHandling** to **NullValueHandling.Ignore** should resolve your issue.

But if still want to treat JSON response as a plain text and want to do string operations, a call to REPLACE (with empty string) using this regex can help you:

```
(\"[^"]+\":null,?|,?\"[^"]+\":null)
```